# Django Production Site keeps going down after 3 weeks

Tags: django, nginx

I am running a website using Django, Gunicorn and Nginx off a Digital Ocean droplet. The website runs fine for about three weeks and then it random stops connecting users to the webpage. When I visit the webpage in my browser it returns:

> This site can’t be reached ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Restarting the droplet fixes the issue, but it will likely happen again after three weeks.

When I check the Gunicorn worker it says its running fine and my Django logs are clean.

Nginx only reported this:

```
2019/08/31 23:11:56 [error] 28183#28183: *36352 open() "/home/projects/server/mysite/static/img/icon.jpg" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.249.64.149, server: removedurl.com, request: "GET /static/img/icon.jpg HTTP/1.1", host: "removedurl.com.com"
```

It seems that restarting Nginx fixes the problem.

**EDIT:**

I just remembered that I have a crontab set up that renews the Letsencrypt SSL certificate, which could be the problem. Here is the crontab command:

```
0 0 1 * * /etc/init.d/nginx stop && /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew &&  /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

**EDIT2:**

The command above is not a great way to go about this, instead I deleted my original letencrypt certification and used the Nginx webserver plugin for Certbot that allowed me to renew the certification through my existing webserver instead of letsencrypt --standalone trying to start up a new webserver on port 80 (which it couldn't)

Comment: Don't stop and restart nginx. `nginx -s reload` should pull in whatever updates it needs (if that's even necessary), and there's no reason for the server to be down while letsencrypt attempts an update... if this is consistently bringing down nginx, you might also be making invalid assumptions about the return value of that renew command.

Comment: When i try to run Letsencrypt to renew the cert, it says that port 80 is already in use by Nginx

Comment: I have letsencrypt running on several servers, including production boxes, which I definitely would not do if it required shutting down the web server, let alone _the entire time_ it updated. And the command you have won't even start nginx again if letsencrypt fails, which is also unacceptable... aside from that, you're using nginx restart, not start, which only makes sense if nginx hasn't already been stopped. I think you need to just start over from the beginning with letsencrypt setup.

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out and fixed the issue!